# LibClang Python binding function "getOverridden"

Tags: python, libclang

LibClang exposes a function to "determine the set of methods that are overridden by the given method" (explained [here](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX__CURSOR__MANIP.html#gac308b03420c550e00c61153dc63deac8)). However this function does not seem to be exposed in the python bindings. Could someone explain how to add this function to the bindings or did I just not find it?

Comment: I found the solution myself. Will post it later at home.

Answer (score 0):

In general, adding methods to libclang follows the same basic pattern used in the library itself.

1. You use ctypes to find a handle to the method you want to wrap.
2. You specify the extra type information about arguments and return types.
3. You wrap that ctypes function in a python function that deals with any corner cases / caching.

For simple cases, you can use [cymbal](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cymbal), a new Python module that came out of some experiments trying to answer this question. Cymbal lets you tack methods onto libclang types and cursors.

However, `clang_getOverriddenCursors` is slightly more complex than normal because you need to dispose of the memory returned by calling `clang_disposeOverriddenCursors`.

Additionally, libclang does some magic that means the cursors you get back from that function aren't valid for all function calls (they omit a pointer to the translation unit), So you also need to generate updated cursors (based on the translation unit and location).

Sample code:

```
import clang.cindex
from clang.cindex import *

clang_getOverriddenCursors = clang.cindex.conf.lib.clang_getOverriddenCursors
clang_getOverriddenCursors.restype = None
clang_getOverriddenCursors.argtypes = [Cursor, POINTER(POINTER(Cursor)), POINTER(c_uint)]

clang_disposeOverriddenCursors = clang.cindex.conf.lib.clang_disposeOverriddenCursors
clang_disposeOverriddenCursors.restype = None
clang_disposeOverriddenCursors.argtypes = [ POINTER(Cursor) ]

def get_overriden_cursors(self):
    cursors = POINTER(Cursor)()
    num = c_uint()
    clang_getOverriddenCursors(self, byref(cursors), byref(num))

    updcursors = []
    for i in xrange(int(num.value)):
        c = cursors[i]
        updcursor = Cursor.from_location(self._tu, c.location)
        updcursors.append( updcursor )

    clang_disposeOverriddenCursors(cursors)

    return updcursors
```

Assuming that you want to parse something like this:

```
// sample.cpp
class foo {
public:
    virtual void f();
};

class bar : public foo {
public:
    virtual void f();
};
```

You can find methods in the tree

```
idx = Index.create()
tu = idx.parse('sample.cpp', args = '-x c++'.split())
methods = []
for c in tu.cursor.walk_preorder():
    if c.kind == CursorKind.CXX_METHOD:
        methods.append(c)
```

You can then see the overrides

```
def show_method(method):
    return method.semantic_parent.spelling + '::' + method.spelling

for m in methods:
    for override in get_overriden_cursors(m):
        print show_method(m), 'overrides', show_method(override)
```

Which for me prints:

```
bar::f overrides foo::f
```